# Complicated image name like flickr does and deny access just to original image

Tags: uploads

If  I upload a given image like my-image.jpg, then following image resizes occurs:

> http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/my-image-100x100.jpg
>   http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/my-image-200x150.jpg
>   http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/my-image-500x300.jpg

also the original image is uploaded:

> http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/my-image.jpg

I have two question about which actions try to:

## 1 Question

Rename image name to a complicated long name like 5702703214_85bfb55948.jpg:

```
http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/5702703214_85bfb55948.jpg

http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/5702703214_85bfb55948-100x100.jpg
http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/5702703214_85bfb55948-200x150.jpg
http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/5702703214_85bfb55948-500x300.jpg
```

## 2 Question

Avoid access to original image uploaded, let access to thumb, medium and large, but deny access just only to the original image uploaded?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create shortened URL function, then add filter on the_content() to replace all img src URL to shortened URL